# Show that every $n >6$ is the sum of two coprime numbers each greater than or equal to $2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that every $n >6$ is the sum of two coprime numbers each greater than or equal to $2$.

I solved the case $n$ is odd by using $n = 2 + (n-2)$, but I don't see how to do the other case.

Reference: Exercise $4.19$ in *Exercices de mathématiques: oraux X-ENS (Algèbre I)*, by Francinou, Gianella and Nicolas.

Comment: Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: i.e. take numbers that are close enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an overkill, but if $n=2k$, by Bertrand postulate there exists some prime $p$ such that $k<p<2k-2=n-2$.

Then
$$n=p+(n-p)$$
works.